# Coding for multiple subreports in visual studio 2010 reportviewer

Tags: c#, ado.net, reportviewer

I have a main report which need to have 2 or more subreports. In Form_Load I coded like this:-

```
cmdReport.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblA; SELECT * FROM tblB; SELECT * FROM tblC";  
// tblA is main report
// execute query by SqlDataReader drReport and load result to dataset dsReport
drReport = cmdReport.EcecuteReader();
dsReport.Load(drReport, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, dsReport.Tables[0], tables[1], Tables[2]);
// prepare report rptMain for view
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "rptMain.rdlc");
// add a handler for SubreportProcessing
reportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler  (SubreportProcessingEventHandler);
// then
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
rds.Name = "DataSet1"   // DataSet1 is the name of DataSet in main and subreports
rds.Value = dsReport.Table[0];
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
// preview the report
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

// In the SubreportProcessingEventHandler I coded thus:-
void SubreportProcessingEventHandler(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{
    e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dsReport.Table[1]));
    e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dsReport.Table[2]));
}
```

In runtime I see report with data from tblA and subreport on tblB. Subreport for tblC only shows static text but data is missing from report!

I shall be grateful if anyone can can guide me on the correct coding so that all subreports data can be displayed in main report.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Should read: "In runtime I see report with data from tblA and subreport on tblB. Subreport for tblC only shows static text but data is missing from report!"

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is from memory, but I believe the Subreport Processing Handler gets called once each time each subreport is processed.  So each subreport generates a separate event each time it needs data.

*So*, you need to determine, in your handler, which subreport is asking for data for that particular call, and supply it with the data it needs.

Comment: the Subreport Processing Handler is called each time the subreport is processed (e.g each master row that is display)  However, I'm adding the data like e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", MyDataForThisRow));, but it seems that this is ignored, and the subreport contains the same data for every row.  Do you know why ?

Comment: I've seen this before, but it's been a long time. First, a basic question: is the name of the dataset in your subreport "DataSet1"?  Also, is the child report parameterized?

Comment: Also, have you got more than one subreport in your report?

Comment: No my DataSet is called Room.   I have posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491898/how-to-use-reportviewer-with-nested-classes-lists-objects